# Как выбрать сводные данные из трёх таблиц?

Tags: mysql, join

Необходимо выбрать данные из трех таблиц:
`data`, `info`, `history`

`data` и `info` имеют уникальные `id` и `sub_id`. Записи из этих таблиц попадают в один объект. К этому объекту нужно добавить массив из таблицы `history`, в которой есть строки с такими же `id` и `sub_id.`

В результате хочу получить объект вида:

```
[result] => array ([0]  => array(  
                       [data.id] => value,
                       [info.id] => value,
                       [history.id] => array(
                                        [0] => array (
                                                 [history.field] => value
                                                 )
                                        [1] => array (
                                                 [history.field] => value
                                                 ),
                  [1]  => array(  
                       [data.id] => value,
                       [info.id] => value,
                       [history.id] => array(
                                        [0] => array (
                                                 [history.field] => value
                                                 )
                                        [1] => array (
                                                 [history.field] => value
                                                 )

    )
```

Comment: Вложенность в своей структуре в любом случае будете руками создавать. А для написания sql запроса нужна структура таблиц с указанием по каким полям они связаны

Comment: они связаны по id и sub_id, проблема в том что я не знаю можно ли join-ом вытащить такую структуру)

Comment: Вложенность запрос не даст. это невозможно. запрос даст плоскую таблицу, которую во время выборки надо самому преобразовывать во вложенную. Т.е. для 0 элемента массива из базы придут 2 записи, которые уже клиент должен положить в вложенно, ориентируясь на их id